# Kubernetes node apparently functioning as master but missing the proper mark

Tags: kubernetes

I have just upgraded a Kubernetes cluster with (so far) two master nodes to v1.16.3. `kubeadm get nodes` marks only one of these nodes with `ROLE master` but the second "master" with "ROLE ". I'm not sure whether this was also the case before the upgrade. However the second "master" runs the prescribed static pods as it should: `etcd`, `kube-apiserver`, `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler`.

Could it be that this is only a matter of the node not being correctly marked but otherwise fully acting as a master? I strongly suspect this is the case (because of the presence of the static pods) and because `kubectl` continues to function even when I force it to contact not the load balancer for `kube-apiserver`s, but the second master directly.)

Am I supposed to add a label `node-role.kubernetes.io/master`?

Comment: can you temporarily shut down the first master and make sure the second one is still working while it is the only one up?

Comment: @PatrickW Good idea. Will try that (after a week of vacation) and report back.

Comment: It could be that labeling won't matter and the node will still act as `master` (I had that scenario with `worker nodes` that were not marked that way but acting in it). You can also check `endpoints` of `kube-scheduler` on that second master using this command: `kubectl get endpoints kube-scheduler -n kube-system -o yaml`. Once you shutdown the first master the second should have `leader` annotation.